# Restoring a Mysql Database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, windows

What i do with this code is:
I ask the user to select a backup to restore(Check)
When the user hit the "Submit" button moves the file to a local carpet of the server(Check)
I call the System function to call mysql.exe to restore the sql file that is in the local server(Problem here)

```
<?php

if($_FILES['enviar']){
$file_name="Respaldo.sql";
move_uploaded_file($_FILE['enviar']['tmp_name'],"Backups/$file_name");
$batche=system("C:/WAMP/BIN/MYSQL/MYSQL5.5.24/bin/mysql.exe -u root test < C:/WAMP/WWW/Backups/respaldo.sql");
echo $batche;

}
?>
```

If i copy exactly this "C:/WAMP/BIN/MYSQL/MYSQL5.5.24/bin/mysql.exe -u root test < C:/WAMP/WWW/Backups/respaldo.sql" into a windows shell it restores the backup without any problem, Any help?.. Thanks

----EDIT---

The problem is that when I call the system function it doesn't do the restoring task, the DB remains Empty.

Comment: You dont have access to PhpMyAdmin or direct database connection?
It's much very simple to restore database with this way.

Comment: are there any PHP errors? What is the value of `$batche`?

Comment: Might or might not be the problem but the directory separator on Windows is backslash (\\), not forward-slash

Comment: No, doesn't throws any php errors, the backslash is not the problem and I need to do it this way, because y need to do the restore with php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$batche=system("C:/WAMP/BIN/MYSQL/MYSQL5.5.24/bin/mysql.exe -u root test < C:/WAMP/WWW/Backups/respaldo.sql");
```

Instead of above code you will replace like below as follows:

```
$batche=**shell_exec** ("C:/WAMP/BIN/MYSQL/MYSQL5.5.24/bin/mysql.exe -u root test < C:/WAMP/WWW/Backups/respaldo.sql");
```